# Create and add framework with cocoapods to iOS app

Tags: swift, frameworks, cocoapods

I want to create iOS static framework that has its own Cocoapods. I want to add this framework to two of my apps, so I think it should be a separate project.

I managed to create my framework (and the main app see its public methods). I connected them using embedded binaries option.

My framework's Podfile looks like this:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'FrameworkBase' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'Alamofire'
  pod 'Timepiece'

   target 'FrameworkTests' do
   end
end
```

My app's Podfile:

```
target 'AppName' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for AppName
  pod 'Alamofire'
  pod 'Timepiece'
end
```

The app builds and works but I have to add my pods (the same) to all projects and it isn't the best solution in my opinion.

1) Is there any way to connect framework that I wouldn't have to import same pods in framework and app if only the framework uses them?

2) How it works when I'll want to use pods functionalities in both app and framework? Can app use pods integrated into framework if the app doesn't have that pods in Podfile?